# Como aplicar un subrayado en un bloque inline

Tags: html, css

Muy buenas, tengo un problema tratando de imitar el diseño de este elemento.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero colocar ese "subrayado" azul con el espacio en el top, sin embargo, no encuentro la solución. Creo que tengo que aplicar el pseudoelemento::after pero me he complicado el doble.

Mi código

```css
div{
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    outline: 1px solid black;
}

span::after{
    height: 3px;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="z.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <span>What you get</span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: agregado, disculpa soy nuevo

Comment: Si, ya la respuesta que coloco @BetaM me funciono :)

Answer (score 3):

No ocupas de un pseudoelemento para el resultado esperado, considero que puedes lograrlo de este modo:

- Le puedes dar un [border](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/border-style) inferior de un grosor y color determinado
- Para lograr la separación entre el texto y la línea dibujada usarías la propeidad [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/padding) con un valor solo para la parte inferior
- Opcionalmente yo movería este texto dentro de una [etiqueta p](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/p)

Código:

```html
    <style>
      .textos {
        border-bottom: 1px solid red;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
      }
    </style>

    <span class="textos">
      What you get!
    </span>
```